# Coercing a LINQ result list of KeyValuePair into a Dictionary - Missing the Concept

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary

I wanted to write this LINQ statement:

```
Dictionary<int, ItemBO> result = ( Dictionary<int, ItemBO> )
    ( from item in originalResults where item.Value.SomeCriteria == true
    select item );
```

`originalResults` is of type `Dictionary<int, ItemBO>`.

I get that `item` is of type `KeyValuePair<int, ItemBO>`, but would have thought that the cast from a list of that type to a Dictionary of that type would have been... er... "Natural".

Instead, to get the compiler to shut up, I needed to write this:

```
Dictionary<int, ItemBO> result = 
    ( from item in originalResults where item.Value.SomeCriteria == true
    select item.Value ).ToDictionary( GetItemKey );
```

Which, although not entirely counter-intuitive, suggests that a lot of unnecessary work unpackaging and repackaging the Dictionary is going on under the covers. Is there a better solution? Is there a concept I'm missing out on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which, although not entirely counter-intuitive, suggests that a lot of unnecessary work unpackaging and repackaging the Dictionary is going on under the covers.

I'm not sure what you mean by "unnecessary" work. To perform this operation requires a lot of work - your query has to be fully evaluated, which involves scanning the entire dictionary and evaluating the predicate for each entry. Also, a new dictionary has to be created and populated to store the results. I think that it would be more of a problem if this work was hidden by an automatic conversion.

The real problem is that you're using your dictionary backwards. Lookups by key are fast, but lookups by value require scanning all items in the dictionary. If you could store the dictionary so that the value you are using to filter is the key then you will be able to make much faster lookups and with a cleaner syntax.

Comment: I didn't *think* I was using my dictionary backwards, but now you're making me reconsider the overall architecture of this module. (I inherited it. It really does need a rewrite, and this may be the titration point.)

Comment: @Bob Kaufman: There may be other places in your code where the dictionary is being used the "right" way and this one place is the exception. If so, it might be OK to leave it as it is, and accept that this one operation is slow, especially if it is called infrequently. But if this is the typical way you are using the dictionary, I would say it's a good idea to consider if another design would be more suitable.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to take another stab at what the *real* "key" concept you're missing is.

If I were to venture a guess, I'd say I *think* you're picturing a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` as synonymous with its contents. *You've got a bunch of key-value pairs—that's a dictionary, right?* And this is where you're missing an important detail. While you certainly *could* implement `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` using, say, a simple `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[]`, this would be missing one of the greatest benefits of having a dictionary type in the first place: fast lookup by key.

Even if you kept the array sorted and used binary search to locate keys (which, by the way, would incur a cost for all insertions), you couldn't compete with the [hash table implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashtable) that `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` uses. This implementation is not simply "a bunch of key-value pairs" with no particular structure; structure is *everything* for this type. Thus a quick cast from a bunch of key-value pairs (content with no structure) straight to a dictionary (with a very particular strucutre) isn't really possible—not that the structural layout of a type really determines whether casting is possible in C# anyway (you have to abide by inheritance alone, and *a few* built-in and possibly user-defined type conversions).

Think of it this way: the dictionary is the container, not the contents, right? So if I have a jar of many different types of cookies, and I want to take out all the chocolate chip cookies, I might extract each one, put them all in a little pile and then say: "Now this is a jar of chocolate chip cookies, right?" No, I've only taken the cookies *out*; what I have is a pile, not a jar. If I want a *jar* of chocolate chip cookies then I'll have to *put them in one*—and that will require some non-zero amount of work.

Answer (score 1):

The concept you're missing is that your code represents a query of an existing dictionary, the results of which will be an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K,V>>`. What your original code is expecting is that somebody defined a conversion for `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K,V>>` to `Dictionary<K,V>`. In essence, they've given you the ability to define whatever conversion you need yourself, as you have the `ToDictionary` extension method which allows you to determine a key, a value, etc.

Answer (score 0):

the "real" result of a linq query is not a dictionary so you cannot naturally cast it.
The result is IQueryable so you have to explicitly convert it.